# How to remove the top and left margin of a tableView's cell that doesn't expect to preserve the super view's inherited margins?

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have, initially, a cell that takes advantage of the default `layoutMargin`

```
(lldb) po self.contentView.layoutMargins
▿ UIEdgeInsets
  - top : 8.0
  - left : 8.0 { ... }
  - bottom : 8.0 { ... }
  - right : 8.0 { ... }
```

I wanted my table view to auto resize the cell while taking advantage of the layout margins, and so, I acomplished this setting some constraints:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.stackView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .TopMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.stackView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .BottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.stackView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.stackView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    ])
```

[image]

Looking good so far!

I now would like to manually update my contentView's `layoutMargin` and so I did this:

```
self.contentView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
self.contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I would expect to have all existing insets set to 0. And they are! Truth be told:

```
(lldb) po self.contentView.layoutMargins
▿ UIEdgeInsets
  - top : 0.0
  - left : 0.0 { ... }
  - bottom : 0.0 { ... }
  - right : 0.0 { ... }
```

However, my interfce looks like this:

[image]

What is causing the top and left margins of my cell to have that margin?

What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't have an immediate answer but you might want to use Xcode's View Debugging feature to capture the screen and see what's affecting the spacing at run time.

Comment: Good suggestion when using IB. I was actually adding 2 aditional constraints with leading and top constants that I forgot. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution described in the question actually works properly. However, I forgot some constraints in my code:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.stackView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 15),
NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.stackView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 15)
```

These constraints were, of course, adding the Top and Leading margin that I did not desire.

My suggestion to anyone facing similar issues is to play close attention to all the constraints that were added throughout the code.